# Qt Signals & Slots: How do I get the data which was changed?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-signals

I have a QStandardModel. I connect its [itemChanged](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#itemChanged) signal to my own slot.

```
m_model = new QStandardItemModel(this);  
connect(m_model, SIGNAL(itemChanged(QStandardItem*)), this, SLOT(changed(QStandardItem*)));
```

The slot looks like this:

```
void Class::changed(QStandardItem * item) {
    //    ui->pushButton->setText("change");
    QString name = item->parent()->data().toString();
    ui->pushButton->setText(item->data().toString());
}
```

The pushButton text will change to "change", so my slot seems to work. However, item->data().toString() is always empty.

How do I do this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `QStandardItem::text()` method. Like this: `QString name = item->parent()->text();`

Comment: Year, this mistake is common in Qt programming.